# Representing regular expressions with DFA state diagrams

Tags: regex, automata, finite-automata, automata-theory

I have these regular expressions:

a) `0(10)*`

b) `a(b+c+d)`

c) `b*(aa*b*+ε)`

I created these state diagrams for them:

[image: Solutions]

Are they correct?

Comment: Please post a representation of your problem directly in this forum.   People are far to savvy to click on arbitrary links.

Comment: Couldn't you wait for 16:20 to post this (4:20 pm), would have been nice. Also good that you're charging your phone.
Usually asking a question is a way to get an answer, the more information you provide the better the chances for getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I deciphered your writing correctly, this is what you wrote:

> a) `0(10)*`
>
> [image]

Correct.

But two remarks:

- Clearly indicate which state is the starting state. It is common to use an incoming arrow for that, like you did in answer to (c).
- The rightmost two states are not really needed as they are indistinguishable from the first two states (at the top).

You could simplify to this:

[image]

> b) `a(b+c+d)`
>
> [image]

Not correct. There are these issues:

- `a` is not a valid input, so the second state should not be an accepting state.
- This first sink state lacks a transition for `a`. Once that is corrected, it becomes a state that is indistinguishable from the second sink, and so they could be merged
- And you should indicate which is the starting state

Correction:

[image]

> c) `b*(aa*b*+ε)`
>
> [image]

Correct!

Comment: Nice diagrams ++